# Android gradle plugin version 8.1.0 causes R imports issues

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When running my codebase using AGP `7.4.2` I am able to run code similar to the following with no imports issues

```
import com.sampleapp.R

R.attr.colorOnSurface --> form com.google.android.material.R
R.dimen.spacing_xsmall --> from my own code
```

After updating to AGP `8.1.1` that code isn't working anymore and I find myself having to do something like the following to get it working

```
import com.google.android.material.R as MaterialR 
import com.sampleapp.R

MaterialR.attr.colorOnSurface
R.dimen.spacing_xsmall
```

I can't find anything in the release notes for AGP v8 that mentions the change in behaviour and I am unsure If I am missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [non-transitive R classes](https://developer.android.com/build/optimize-your-build#use-non-transitive-r-classes) which became [enabled by default](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-0-0-release-notes#default-changes) in Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. Because of the faster build benefits for multi-module apps it is recommended to use them. If you cannot migrate to using them for some reason at this time they can still be disabled by setting the following in your `gradle.properties` file.

`android.nonTransitiveRClass=false`